# Using WFS with layers with leaflet 1.0 generates an error

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet, layer

I'm having a problem using Leaflet 1.2.0 with WFS and control Layers, WFS works fine, however when I use it with control.layers (see code bellow) it does not work and it returns an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'minZoom' of undefined
```

If using with version 0.6 works but I can not use it because of its limitations. Can someone please help me?

The code is here in git:
https://github.com/eltonsantos/leaflet-tests/blob/master/teste14/index.html

and here in jsfiddle:
    https://jsfiddle.net/eltin182/amg80r7j/3/

Answer (score 0):

You are building a plain JS object:

```js
var stComerciaisLayer = {
  service: 'WFS',
  // etc.
};
```

…and try to feed it into the Leaflet Layers Control:

```js
var objCamadas = {
  "Setores Comerciais": stComerciaisLayer
}

L.control.layers(baseLayers, objCamadas).addTo(map);
```

…whereas the Layers Control is supposed to handle Leaflet layers, not plain JS objects.

There should be some Leaflet plugins to handle WFS, have a look on the [plugins page](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html).